# npm upgrade stuck at version 6.9.0

Tags: upgrade, version, npm

Can you find the solution conerning the update of npm, indeed when i try to install or upgrade npm to version 10.15.3, i'm sill stuck at the version 6.9.0 and i don't understand the reason.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: We cannot possibly help with so little information. Please update your question to include what you have tried and what messages resulted. Also include your OS, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry !

I work on Windows 10.
My initial objective was to install Vue Js, but on the internet they say that i should 
 not use my actual version of npm, is not recommended for a Vue JS installation. 
So I tried to install the latest version from the official site (10.15.3), however by doing the command npm -v it displays me 6.9.0.
So I tried the command npm install -g npm@latest 
It seems like it not working, i see again 6.9.0.

Comment: How to close this topic ? I guess there is no solution exept to change my computer.